# Javascript ways of instantiation the class and directly calling the method

Tags: javascript, oop

What is the correct way of creating instance of the class and directly call the method?

normally I use:

```
var obj = new Class();
obj.method();
```

if I want to call the method without creating a new variable which way is correct and what is difference between these options?

1. `new Class().method()`
   or
2. `(new Class()).method()`

When and why should I use 1. or 2. option?

thanks a lot

Comment: Those two lines behave exactly the same. The second one just has extra parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no practical difference between those two options.

The parentheses are redundant, just as they are in the expression `(1 + 2) + 3`.